# Paperclip avatar displays image title, not image

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I recently cloned my application onto a new computer, and downloaded Imagemagick. I'm using the Paperclip gem to add avatars to Users. On the old computer Paperclip worked perfectly, but on the new one, though the User appears to save the avatar, `<%= image_tag @user.avatar_url(:size) %>` displays the image's title, not the image itself. The only thing I can think of is that I may have downloaded a different form of Imagemagick, because everything else I bundle installed. Does anyone with Paperclip experience know what might be causing this?

Avatars are saved in my `application/public/system/users/avatars/000/000` folder.

**views/users/crop.html.erb**

```
<% content_for(:head) do %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "jquery.Jcrop" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.Jcrop.min" %>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
ready = $(function() {
  $("#cropbox").Jcrop();
});
</script>
<% end %>

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);

<%= image_tag @user.avatar.url(:large), :id => "cropbox" %>
```

**Gemfile:**

```
gem "paperclip", :git => "git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git"
# ...
```

**models/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :large => "500x500", :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "50x50!" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
  # ...
```

**controllers/users.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def create
    # ...
    if @user.save
      render :action => "crop"
    else
      flash[:notice] = "Failed"
      redirect_to new_user_path
    end
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :avatar)
    end
```

**views/users/new.html.erb**

```
  <%= form_for @user, :url => users_path, :html => { :multipart => true } do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :name, :placeholder => "Name" %>
    <br>
    <%= f.label :display_picture %>
    <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
    <br>
    <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
```

**schema.rb**

```
# ...

create_table "users", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.string   "avatar_file_name"
  t.string   "avatar_content_type"
  t.integer  "avatar_file_size"
  t.datetime "avatar_updated_at"
  # ...
end
```

Comment: So a url is listed instead of the picutre? Does the path listed match up with the actual location of the image?

Comment: No, the image title. So for example if the image is Picture.jpg, it just displays the text "Picture".

Comment: I have an app with the exact same code... what version of ruby/rails?

Comment: It's possible to try doing gem "paperclip".  By specifying the git url I think you're on the bleeding edge (this is likely not your problem, but worth eliminating...). Then run bundle install

Comment: Did you do the required migrations? post your User schema please

Comment: @Peege151 Posted the schema above. I'm using Ruby 2.0.0 and Rail 4.0.10. By gem "paperclip" do you mean I should delete the link?

Comment: Yeah you could try that... that's about the only difference in our code that I've noticed...

Comment: @Peege151 Hm, no that didn't help either.

Comment: Have you restarted your server?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64602/discussion-between-peege151-and-user3739453).

Comment: @Peege151 Argh I always forget to do that... it works now! Thanks a lot! You should add that as an answer so I can accept it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If everything seems right with your code, sometimes everything is actually right with your code.

To save yourself from hair-pulling issues like this, have a checklist

1. **Make sure the code you're viewing is the code you're changing**: Sometimes, when working in different environments, we as programmers get tired or confused, and briefly realize our changes aren't occurring because we haven't pushed them up to heroku, or because we're referencing the wrong port on localhost =)
2. **Restart Server With Significant Change**:  Anytime you change config.rb, or run a `bundle install` I recommend restarting your server.  You may not need to, but try this at the first sign of error.
3. **Wipe your Database If It Safe To Do So**: When you are dealing with nilClass or undefined method errors, it's possible that you have old data in your database -- you may have added a column, etc. and old record do not have that, so your app errors out.